# Why differents SOAP clients speak differents XML dialect?

Tags: xml, soap

Using a .Net Soap client and my WSF/PHP client to call the same SOAP service, I can see differences between the XML sent.

Here is mine :

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
    <soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Action>http://www.aaa.fr/SendMessage</soapenv:Action>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
            <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EncKeyID-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx">
```

Here is .Net XML :

```
<s:Envelope>
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_3">http://www.aaa.fr/SendMessage</a:Action>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1">
            <e:EncryptedKey Id="EncKeyID-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx">
```

I am not a specialist in XML nor SOAP, but is it a big deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the definition of the namespacing prefixes. As long as the namespace prefix "s" points to the same namespace as "soapenv", and "o" points to the same namespace as "wsse", and "e" points to the same namespace as "xenc" etc. etc. there should be no problems, the XML is effectively the same.

Example:

```
<a:NodeA xmlns:a="http://www.a.com">
    <b:NodeB xmlns:b="http://www.b.com">
        <c:NodeC xmlns:c="http://www.c.com">My Data!</c:NodeC>
    </b:NodeB>
</a:NodeA>
```

Is identical to

```
<anamespace:NodeA xmlns:anamespace="http://www.a.com">
    <bns:NodeB xmlns:bns="http://www.b.com">
        <c:NodeC xmlns:c="http://www.c.com">My Data!</c:NodeC>
    </bns:NodeB>
</anamespace:NodeA>
```

because even though the prefixes are different, they point to the same namespace in both examples (http://www.a.com, http://www.b.com and http://www.c.com respectively).